# A difficulty in understanding the proof of Riemann Lebesgue lemma.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The proof is given below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**My questions are:**

1- In the second line from below how do we get $2/|\lambda|$ (in the second term) from the line before  it.

2- What is the lemma trying to say?

Comment: 1. $|\sin t|\le 1$. 2. It's saying that the Fourier transform "vanishes at $\infty$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, consider

$$ \max_{x_1,x_2} \left|\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\cos (x) dx \right|= \max_{x_1,x_2} \left|\sin (x) \big|_{x_1}^{x_2}\right| = 2.$$

That is, the maximum value of $\sin(x_2)-\sin(x_1)$ is 2. For an example, you can take $x_1=-\pi/2$ and $x_2=\pi/2$. The proof continues by using

$$\left|\sin (x) \big|_{x_1}^{x_2}\right| \le 2.$$

For the second question, the lemma itself says that the integral of an integrable function $F$ against a sinusoidal function will vanish in the limit of infinite oscillations over a finite interval. Basically, there are as many positive contributions as negative due to the infinite frequency, so the result is zero.

Comment: Could you please check the relation between $\lambda$ and L, as I can see that it is incorrect ...... or do I have something wrong in my mind?

Comment: I don't see it. Which statement do you have in mind?

Comment: This part looks fine, if that's what you mean: If $\lambda \ge L = 4 \sum_i \frac{|m_i|}{\epsilon +1}$, then $\lambda > 4 \sum_i \frac{|m_i|}{\epsilon}$, so $\frac{1}{\lambda} < \frac{\epsilon}{4\sum_i |m_i|}$. They then subtitute this into the last line, and I see no issues there.